# Storing and outputting word.length() into an array

Tags: c++, file-io, count, static-libraries, string-length

I have been at this for a few hours and I am having difficulty reading into my text file, counting how many letters each word has, the amount of words for every amount of letters.

I have come up with this, thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int array_size = 29;

int main() {

ifstream inputfile;
string word, word2;
int wordlength[array_size];
int length = 0;

cout << left << setw(10) << "Length: ";
cout << left << setw(10) << "# of words: " << endl;

inputfile.open("C:/EnglishWords.txt");

while (inputfile) {

    inputfile >> word;

    int len = word.length(); 
    wordlength[len]++; //initialized array for '29'

    for (int i = 1; i < 29; i++) {
        cout << left << setw(10) << wordlength[i];
        cout << left << setw(10) << i;
    }
}

getchar();
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

I am essentially getting variations of -8293729 (I am assuming this is garbage memory) for each actual value that I want printed. I could really use the power of stackoverflow on this one because I am stumped :/.

EDIT: My file that I am reading from is a list of "all" the English words separated by /n;

Comment: Besides the nested `for` loop (oh, that's a missing `}`? thanks for the [MCVE]) and checking stream for errors **before** extraction, you didn't show us the error. `wordlength` has probably uninitialized elements. It should be `std::map`...

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I did add the '}' at the end of my while loop. So that is not the problem. I am a bit confused as to how I would show you the error, by providing the int main() section so you can compile it? Also, I am brand new to coding, I am a bit confused as to how I should implement map, I looked it up, but still am a bit lost. Thanks again for responding!

Comment: This `while` loop should probably be `while( inputFile >> word) { ... }`

Comment: Your code is not rendering correctly in your question since you added your missing `}`, can you fix it?

Comment: I fixed the '{' problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `wordlentgth` array is not initialized.
Try using a for loop to set its content to 0 before incrementing it. Or, better yet, use [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset)

```
int wordlength[array_size];
memset(wordlength, 0, array_size);
```

EDIT: `int wordlength[array_size] = {0};` is the way to go in this case. `memset` is useful when you have to re-set an array for example.

You will need to `#include <cstring>` in order to use it.

Second, if any of the word is greater than `array_size` your program will crash because of a segmentation fault (you should look it up, it will be the most frequent error you will encounter if you program in C/C++). In order to avoid this bug, just make sure that `len` is lesser than `array_size` before incrementing `wordlength[len]` by wrapping the increment in an if:

```
int len = word.length(); 
if(len < array_size) {
    wordlength[len]++;
} else {
    cerr << "A word was ignored because it was too long: \"" << word << "\"\n";
}
```

Lastly, you should read a little bit about naming conventions. It is a matter of preference really, but just try to be consistent (i.e. `wordlength` doesn't follow the same convention that `array_size`). The way you wrote `array_size` is called `snake-case` and I personally like it, but the mainstream style in the C family of language is CamelCase.
Another note about style: it is *ok* to use global constants, but it is really recommended to name it so it is clear that it is a constant: `ARRAY_SIZE` instead of `array_size`.

Also, indent your code correctly. Better yet, use an editor that can auto-indent your code.

Comment: Truly appreciate all of the advice man. I do use Visual Studio and keep the way it is formatted, but when I paste my code into the box, I have to indent it 4 spaces and it messes everything up. I will definitely read into all of those things. Thank you!
I am going to give the initialization a try and see what happens, also, I will try to set 'len' to 0 to make it 'lesser' than array size?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Wouldn't value-initializing `wordlength` be enough to initialize it to 0? For example: `int wordlength[array_size]{}` or `int wordlength[array_size] = {0}`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault your totally right, I forgot about that, silly me

Comment: Hey, So I found a solution to my problem, all I changed was the int wordlength [array_size] = {0} and everything is working perfectly. 

I am new to this website too, am I supposed to mark this as solved? or post my final code to let people know I fixed it?

Comment: @Complexicator, I've edited my answer to better explain what I meant by "make sure len is lesser than array_size". Plus I've added what KABoissoneault said.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to clarify, I solved my issue by initializing my array.

I added:

```
int wordlength[array_size] = {0};
```

to the top of my file and the dump memory was no longer outputted.

Thanks to all that helped :)